# What does this ejabberd / erlang stack trace mean?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

could someone help me figure out what to look for in this stacktrace? I've never touched Erlang, so I don't really know where to start.

We're using v19.09 of ejabberd, and getting this error log for many users:

```
2020-03-14 15:29:31.096 [error] <0.2029.48>@mod_http_api:handle:257 REST API Error: set_presence([{<<"user">>,<<"53265363">>},{<<"host">>,<<"chat.us.com">>},{<<"resource">>,<<"ssid-3465">>},{<<"type">>,<<"available">>},{<<"show">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"status">>,<<"{\"current_lobby_id\":\"none\",\"status\":\"{\\r\
\\t\\\"rich_presence\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"rich_presence\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"?s=PlayerStatusInMap?p0=21?p1=2?p2=3\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"session_id\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"ssid-3465-38a44f60-9df7-4c79-8c8e-1cc99e5039dd\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\
}\\\",\\r\
\\t\\\"current_lobby_id\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"lobby_id\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"c791cfaa-9fd3-4d0d-9d5c-1aeb9efb12e2@hangouts.chat.us.com\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"privacy\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"friends_only\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\
}\\\"\\r\
}\",\"region\":\"\"}">>},{<<"priority">>,<<"0">>}]) -> exit:{noproc,{p1_server,call,[none,{set_presence,{presence,<<>>,available,<<>>,{jid,<<"953265363">>,<<"chat.us.com">>,<<"oak/ssid-3465-1cc99e5039dd">>,<<"1953265363">>,<<"chat.us.com">>,<<"4c79-8c8e-1cc99e5039dd">>},{jid,<<"1953265363">>,<<"chat.us.com">>,<<>>,<<"1953265363">>,<<"chat.us.com">>,<<>>},chat,[{text,<<"en">>,<<"{\"current_lobby_id\":\"none\",\"status\":\"{\\r\
\\t\\\"rich_presence\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"rich_presence\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"?s=PlayerStatusInMap?p0=21?p1=2?p2=3\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"session_id\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"ssid-348c8e-1cc99e5039dd\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\
}\\\",\\r\
\\t\\\"current_lobby_id\\\": \\\"{\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"lobby_id\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"c791cfaa-9fd3-4d0d-9d5c-1aeb9efb12e2@hangouts.chat.us.com\\\\\\\",\\\\r\\\
\\\\t\\\\\\\"privacy\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"friends_only\\\\\\\"\\\\r\\\
}\\\"\\r\
}\",\"region\":\"\"}">>}],0,[],#{}}},1000]}} [{p1_server,call,3,[{file,"src/p1_server.erl"},{line,210}]},{mod_http_api,handle2,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,267}]},{mod_http_api,handle,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,228}]},{mod_http_api,perform_call,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,188}]},{mod_http_api,process,2,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,141}]},{ejabberd_http,process,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,366}]},{ejabberd_http,process_request,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,488}]},{ejabberd_http,process_header,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,286}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the actual error, which is buried in the middle:

```
exit:{noproc,{p1_server,call,[none,{set_presence,.....
```

So there is a `noproc` error, which occurred during a call to `p1_server:call`, where the first argument is `none`.  (The call would look like `p1_server:call(none, {set_presence,...})`.)  That is, we're asking the process called `none` to execute the command `set_presence`, which fails because there is no process registered with the name `none`.

Now let's look at the stack trace.  I added line breaks:

```
[{p1_server,call,3,[{file,"src/p1_server.erl"},{line,210}]},
 {mod_http_api,handle2,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,267}]},
 {mod_http_api,handle,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,228}]},
 {mod_http_api,perform_call,4,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,188}]},
 {mod_http_api,process,2,[{file,"src/mod_http_api.erl"},{line,141}]},
 {ejabberd_http,process,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,366}]},
 {ejabberd_http,process_request,1,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,488}]},
 {ejabberd_http,process_header,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,286}]}]
```

The first line is where it discovers that there is no such process, on [line 210 in `p1_server.erl`](https://github.com/processone/p1_utils/blob/14766d690709359ffcbccb930d221f5c570766de/src/p1_server.erl#L210).  But we're more interested in *why* we're passing `none` as the argument in the first place.  The stack trace suggests that's happening somewhere in [`mod_http_api.erl`](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/19.09/src/mod_http_api.erl), but at that point I'm getting lost - it seems like it's extracting the arguments from the command, but I don't understand where the `none` is coming from...